# Adaptar grandle a el android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES

Tags: android, android-studio

Cuando corro mi aplicacion apesar de q no genera error no c ve en ningun dispositivo y genera estae mensaje??

Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details.

Comment: Efrain agrega tu manifest.xml y build.gradle ademas comenta que version de OS android tienen tus dispositivos donde no se despliega correctente.

Answer (score 1):

No tenes que usar android:maxSdkVersion tan baja, porque si tratas de correrlo en un sistema con android mas moderno no funcionara, proba cambiar el maxSdk por algo mas grande, como 19 (kitkat 4.4.2),por 21(Lollipop), o por 23 (Marshmallow). seguramente con eso funcionara a la perfeccion!

Answer (score 1):

Si tu app no se ve en alguno dispositivos, seguramente no tienes definido un minSdkVersion o tu targetSdkVersion es muy reciente, lo comun es declarar un minSdkVersion con el cual funcionara tu app y un targetSdkVersion, por ejemplo:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

En cuanto a tu problema te pongo como ejemplo: Si tuvieras un dispositivo con KitKat, android 19 y tuvieras definido un targetSdkVersion de 17 esta no se cargaria, para eso tendrias que definir un valor mayor o igual a 19 de targetSdkVersion .

Aqui puedes ver los valores de las APIs para que configures correctamente tu aplicación.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Answer (score -1):

Realize algunos cambios y quedo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta para no crear respuestas y coloca código no imagen.